# How can I make sure that an LDA implementation works?

Tags: time-series, classification, neural-networks, feature-engineering, discriminant-analysis

I am currently experimenting with neural nets for classification of on-line handwritten data (hence: not pixels, but time series data). To do so, I use several toolkits (internal development of my university). One toolkit I use is [`pfile_utils`](http://www1.icsi.berkeley.edu/~dpwe/projects/sprach/sprachcore.html). It offers an [Linear discriminant analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis) (LDA) implementation. However, when I apply this LDA implementation my neural net gets an error rate of 1 on the validation set (and the test set). So after LDA it the neural net does not recognize anything.

I thought that LDA would in the worst case change nothing. So I think this might be an implementation error.

Is there any dataset for neural nets where it was showed that LDA significantly improves the recognition rate? How could I otherwise check if the LDA implementation is correct?

Currently, my features are calculated like this:

- Get the data. The data is grouped by strokes. Every stroke consists of triples (x, y, time).
- Get the first 4 strokes. Discard the rest. Linear interpolate every stroke. Get 20 points for each stroke (spaced evenly in time).
- Get x and y coordinates
- => 4*20*2 = 160 features
- Then apply LDA to those

I think the problem might also be that there is a relationship between the features which the neural net seems to recognize. When I apply LDA this relationship gets broken. Could that be? Is there any literature for LDA and time series data classification?

Comment: What is `LDA`, moose?

Comment: [Linear discriminant analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis) - I add it to the question.

Comment: What output from the LDA are you dumping into your neural network?  

Also note that LDA is going to break the feature space by hyperplanes, if your groups are not easily separated by hyperplanes (consider a donut hole inside a donut) then LDA isn't going to help much.  If you can, you might want to do some plots of your important features first, or some random features first to get a feel for your data.